# MySQL EF 6 v 8.2.0 - Couldn't connect to update model

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6

I've a solution in C# VS2017 in which I use MySQL EF6. When I updated MySQL packages from Nuget and MySql Connector to last version I started facing this errors:

From Server Explorers when trying to connect to all dbs:

[image: ServerExplorers]

When clicking update I see this:

[image: FirstPart]

[image: SecondPart]

When trying to update model from designer I have this output:

[image: DesignerOutput]

And these are my nuget packages

[image: Packages]

My App.config:

```
  <configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
   </configSections>

    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <providers>
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
         </providers>
     </entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an error on MySQL for Visual Studio. Has to remove and re install. After that, reopen VS.